# How does the key form the cipher?

Tags: encryption, stream, block

When a user chooses a key how is that key turned into a cipher (either block or stream cipher) to encrypt the data with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't turned into a cipher. It is used as input of the algorithm of the cipher. Mostly there is some kind of sub-key derivation internally (expanding the key size to create a larger internal state), which is then used to perform e.g. addition, xorring and the like on the data, until you cannot retrieve the orginal data without the key. The cipher itself never changes, only the internal state does.

Comment: Thanks for the answer helped out on the research

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the cipher. Read the specification for whatever cipher you're working with. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#Description_of_the_cipher or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4 .